# Showing that $x \sin\left(\frac1x\right) - y \sin\left(\frac1y\right)\leq |x+y|$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a part of the solution in my textbook but I don't get it. Can somebody explain how this is true.

$$x \sin\left(\frac1x\right) - y \sin\left(\frac1y\right)\leq |x+y|$$

Answer (score 3):

$-1 \leq \sin \left (\frac 1 x \right ), \sin \left ( \frac 1 y \right ) \leq 1,$ for all $x,y \neq 0.$ So for $x,y > 0$ $$-x - y  \leq x \sin \left ( \frac 1 x \right ) - y \sin \left ( \frac 1 y \right ) \leq x+y.$$

For other values of $x$ and $y$ the inequality can be similarly obtained.

Comment: Needs correction. How can you have $-x-y \leq x+y$ for all $x,y \neq 0$?.

Comment: Sorry @Kavi Rama Murthy sir. This is only for $x,y>0.$ The inequality will be reversed if $x,y<0.$ Isn't it so?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. You have correct the proof by changing $x,y \neq 0$ to $x,y >0$. Otherwise the proof is wrong.

Comment: There are also two other cases. $x>0,y<0$ and $x<0,y>0.$

Comment: Fixed it. Please verify it once again @Kavi Rama Murthy sir.

Comment: Yes, it is fine now.